# Div heights matching sub divs

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to space out my divs so they slot in under each other on the page. The problem I'm having (as shown in image) is that I can't get the height of the div to be the same as the div children of it. In this example I have my "box1" and 2 "sub-boxes". The sub-boxes have the text inside but the main div which contains them doesn't have any height.

This is an issue because when I try to add in divs underneath this one they just slot in at the same place as the top one.

[image: screenshot of issue]

If my problem isn't clear please say and I'll try to elaborate

Here is a quick snippet of HTML

```
<div id="aboutus-box1">
<div id="aboutus-box1sub1">
    <span id="subtitle">What is this site all about</span><br/>
    Information and details about the site, point put forwards to new users to look to the help page for support and to look at the <a id="textlink">site rules</a> TEXT FILLER ------------------------------------------- ----------------------------- ------------------ ------------------------- --------------------- --------------------------------- ----------------------- -------------------------- -------------------------------- ----- -------------------------------------- ----------------------------- ------------------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------------------ ----------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------
</div>
<div id="aboutus-box1sub2">
    <span id="subtitle">Our History</span><br/>
    How the group came about, where different members came from, how the idea came about TEXT FILLER ------------------------------------------- ----------------------------- ------------------ ------------------------- --------------------- --------------------------------- ----------------------- -------------------------- -------------------------------- ----- -------------------------------------- ----------------------------- ------------------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------------------ ----------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------
</div></div>
```

And some CSS

```
#aboutus-box1{
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:1%;
    margin-top:1%;
    }
#aboutus-box1sub1{
    height:100%;
    width:49.5%;
    float:left;
    }
#aboutus-box1sub2{
    height:100%;
    width:49.5%;
    float:right;
    margin-left:1%
    }
```

Here's a **[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FEkcr/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent (#aboutus-box1) needs another style: `overflow: hidden;`

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using `float` you need to use also the `clear` property to make the parent preserve the `height`.

```
 #aboutus-box1:after{
    content:" ";
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
```

You can check here [**More About Floats**](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) and other ways to use the `clear` property.

Your [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FEkcr/1/)

Comment: Could you explain why all of those properties are needed? And why not go with Brian's suggestion of using overflow: hidden; ?

Comment: Those properties are needed to place an `:after clear` element... Why not to go with `overflow:hidden` is just choice I prefer not to work with that because overflow isn't the exactly property to clear floats and may cause issues with another contents. But can be more explained in the article I link.

Comment: Thanks for your help, going with overflow:hidden. Appreciate your time

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear your floats in order for the layout to resume.

There are many ways to do this, the simplest being a clearing div after your last floated element.

```
<div class='clear'></div>
```

CSS:

```
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```